# Error when using Raster Calculator in ArcGIS to compute NDVI, Process output is binary, limited to pixels that are either 0 or -1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, remote-sensing, raster-calculator, ndvi

I am using WorldView-3 satellite images that have been orthorectified and corrected to sensor reflectance values to compute a set of normalized difference indexes, including NDVI in ArcGIS version 10.31. While I am aware that it is possible to automatically compute NDVI in Image Analysis, I want to try the operation in Raster Calculator since NDVI is not the only index that I wish to compute.

However, whenever I run the operation (with any of the indexes that I am interested in using), the result is always the same. I obtain a binary raster output, in which pixels are either 0 or -1. The exact same pixels, no matter the type of index and bands that I choose. This is weird since when I manually calculate these indexes for the reflectance values in a set of control points, the result shows that the image should lead to an output that as expected ranges from 1 to -1.

The formula that I have been inputting into the raster calculator is the following.

```
((NIR2 - Red)/(NIR2 + Red))
```

To add more context, the site that I am working at is a peninsula in the north of Madagascar. The 0 values are always restricted to the land and the -1 values are restricted to the surrounding ocean and a small lagoon. The WorldView dataset is stored as a 16-bit TIFF file, containing the 8 multispectral bands that the satellite's sensor pics up. To run the raster calculation, I extracted the bands using ArcCatalog and opened them independently in ArcGIS.

Has anyone ever run into a problem like this?

Or does anyone have an idea of what is causing the problem?

Comment: Try to use float(nominator) etc